# I can't seem to understand why Firebase returns error 400 when my web app works fine locally

Tags: javascript, firebase, get, fetch, bad-request

I made a project in javascript with Vue 2. My project consist of getting data from the Binance API through an URL.

To get the data I'm using the fetch API. With the data, I'm basically storing it in variables and then I'm applying some basic arithmetic.

Locally, everything works fine, but my goal is to publish my project as a web application. For that, I wanted to use Firebase.

I've followed the documentation to deploy my project. On my dashboard I can clearly see that my project is fully deployed. The issue comes when I click on the provided link. My web application throws me an error of : 400 Bad Request. I wonder if there's an interference between Firebase and me fetching data through an URL?

I wonder if anybody could help me I can't seem to figure out what creates this error?

Sorry for uploading my code through the code snippet. I couldn't manage to show my code with the code sample formater This is my first time ever uploading on Stackoverflow...

Here is my main component :

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="subContainer">
      <button @click="toggleBest">+</button>
      <h1 style="text-align:center">Best Futures</h1>
      <div v-if="showBest">
        <div class="displayCoins">
          <label>Nom</label>
          <label>Prix 1</label>
          <label>Prix </label>
        </div>
        <div class="bestFuture">
          <div>{{ max_object_first_future.name }}</div>
          <div>{{ max_object_first_future.first_contract }}%</div>
          <div>-</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bestFuture">
          <div>{{ max_object_second_future.name }}</div>
          <div>-</div>
          <div>{{ max_object_second_future.second_contract }}%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="subContainer">
      <button @click="toggleLog">+</button>
      <h1 style="text-align:center">Futures Log</h1>
      <div v-if="showLog">
        <div class="displayCoins">
          <label>Nom</label>
          <label>Prix 1</label>
          <label>Prix 2</label>
        </div>
        <crypto-coin
          v-for="(future, idx) in futures_array"
          :key="idx"
          :cryptoName="future.name"
          :firstContract="future.first_contract"
          :secondContract="future.second_contract"
        >
        </crypto-coin>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import CryptoCoin from "./CryptoCoin.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    CryptoCoin,
  },
  created() {
    this.dataGetter();
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url: "https://dapi.binance.com//dapi/v1/ticker/bookTicker",
      max_object_first_future: {},
      max_object_second_future: {},
      showLog: false,
      showBest: false,
      futures_array: [
        {
          name: "BTC",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "ETH",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "LINK",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "BNB",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "TRX",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "DOT",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "ADA",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "EOS",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "LTC",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },

        {
          name: "BCH",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "XRP",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "ETC",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "FIL",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "EGLD",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "DOGE",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "UNI",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "THETA",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
        {
          name: "XLM",
          data: [],
          first_contract: 0,
          second_contract: 0,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleLog() {
      this.showLog = !this.showLog;
    },
    toggleBest() {
      this.showBest = !this.showBest;
    },
    async dataGetter() {
      setInterval(async () => {
        this.resetData(this.futures_array);
        const response = await fetch(this.url);
        const data = await response.json();
        for (let prop in data) {
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "BTCUSD") {
            this.futures_array[0].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "ETHUSD") {
            this.futures_array[1].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "LINKUSD") {
            this.futures_array[2].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "BNBUSD") {
            this.futures_array[3].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "TRXUSD") {
            this.futures_array[4].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "DOTUSD") {
            this.futures_array[5].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "ADAUSD") {
            this.futures_array[6].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "EOSUSD") {
            this.futures_array[7].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "LTCUSD") {
            this.futures_array[8].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "BCHUSD") {
            this.futures_array[9].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "XRPUSD") {
            this.futures_array[10].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "ETCUSD") {
            this.futures_array[11].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "FILUSD") {
            this.futures_array[12].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "EGLDUSD") {
            this.futures_array[13].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "DOGEUSD") {
            this.futures_array[14].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "UNIUSD") {
            this.futures_array[15].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "THETAUSD") {
            this.futures_array[16].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
          if (data[prop]["pair"] === "XLMUSD") {
            this.futures_array[17].data.push(data[prop]);
          }
        }
        for (const coins in this.futures_array) {
          this.calculateFutures(this.futures_array[coins]);
        }
        this.findMaxValue(this.futures_array);
      }, 2000);
    },
    resetData(array) {
      for (const coin in array) {
        array[coin].data = [];
        array[coin].first_contract = 0;
        array[coin].second_contract = 0;
      }
    },
    calculateFutures(object) {
      object.first_contract = 0;
      object.second_contract = 0;
      if (object.data.length === 1) {
        object.first_contract = 0;
        object.second_contract = 0;
      }
      if (object.data.length === 2) {
        object.first_contract = parseFloat(
          ((object.data[1].bidPrice / object.data[0].bidPrice - 1) * 100).toPrecision(7)
        );
      }
      if (object.data.length === 3) {
        object.first_contract = parseFloat(
          ((object.data[1].bidPrice / object.data[0].bidPrice - 1) * 100).toPrecision(7)
        );
        object.second_contract = parseFloat(
          ((object.data[2].bidPrice / object.data[0].bidPrice - 1) * 100).toPrecision(7)
        );
      }
    },
    findMaxValue(array) {
      let max_first_future = Math.max(...array.map((value) => value.first_contract));
      let max_second_future = Math.max(...array.map((value) => value.second_contract));
      max_first_future.toFixed(4);
      max_second_future.toFixed(4);
      this.max_object_first_future = array.find((value) => value.first_contract === max_first_future);
      this.max_object_second_future = array.find((value) => value.second_contract === max_second_future);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: My guess would be malformed syntax. I'd add a console log to your request object to see the shape and see what the server is expecting. My guess is they don't line up.

Comment: I've actually found out what was the issue. On creating a project, VueJs adds this path you the img source of the favicon `href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico"` . 

What happened is firebase doesn't recognize this path. All I had to do is remove the `<%= BASE_URL %>` so the href could be `href="favicon.ico"` . After that everything worked beautifully

Thanks for your help, it was much appreciated though

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. That would be malformed syntax (incorrect structure/data/path), for future reference. :)